# Is possible to send files through sms (not in mms) in Android?

Tags: java, android, sms, mms

Is any possible to **send the file through sms**? I want to **encrypt the file** to string format and sent it. The **encrypted file to be decrypted** after receiving the text message. Is this possible in android apps?

Comment: Sure... (see RFC 1149/2549 for a more extreme proposal) but it's silly and expensive and you'll likely run into throttling by the carrier if your file is of any length.

Answer (score 5):

Its SMS ( Short Message Service). You can send limited amount of text via SMS not file.

Read Wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service

If you want to deal with files better to have your own app which encrypts/decrypts file data.  you will have total control on files and data.

If you still want to use SMS. divide the file data in multiple chunks and send it via SMS API. Have your app to read SMS by registering through `Broadcast receiver` and `READ_SMS` permission in your manifest.After reading decrypt the data and store in a file. Now you have the decrypted data stored in destination device. You can show the data on your App.

**Disadvantage** : Because you are sending data using carrier , It does not give any guarantee for when or whether data will be delivered or not. Also now you playing with data chunks you will have to take care for sequence of data as well. Other wise you will be in mess.

Comment: A file can be broken up and encoded into multiple units comprising limited amounts of text, then reassembled.

Comment: I agree ,but at the receiving end you still can't show the complete data if the file data is huge. Traditional SMS Application has limitation to show data.

Comment: @BrijeshThakur if one is using their own app, they can receive the SMSs using it, and re-group them into one file.

Comment: Agree but the point is if the one using their own app , then why he is restricted to send the data using SMS. Better to send the file using dropbox or google drive and and have complete control over it. I recommended the same thing.

Comment: Its ok, but i want to do that for my learning. could you explain?

Comment: @BrijeshThakur What if one does not want to use the internet/data at all :) ? By the way, your answer seems to explain the logical algorithm correctly, as in I agree with it :P

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, but there are too many limitations to make this practical.**

First of all, what most people don't know about SMS sending on Android is that it has a **limitation of 100 SMS per hour** unless you root the phone. And even if you are the only one to send SMS, the files will probably be too big.

There was a library once for the sharing of data through SMS called [Mobile Push (droidpush)](https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-java-push/), but it is no longer available